# How to get a reference to a particular component in an Angular2 template?

Tags: dart, angular

I know that Angular2 has `@ViewQuery` to get a `QueryList` of components matching the given type. But is there a way to get a reference to a particular component in this `QueryList`?

Right now, the only way I can think to do this is to give the component an extra "id" field, then iterate through the `QueryList` and check if the identifier is the one I want, e.g.:

```
getComponentById(QueryList<HasIdField> queryList, String id) =>
    queryList.singleWhere((component) => component.id == id);
```

But this seems like a common enough problem that it seems like there should be a way to do this without adding this "id" boilerplate. I know that a component can be referenced locally within a template using `#`, but is there a way to reference a component similarly within a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this functionality does not exist, see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3034) for details on why the functionality to implement a custom filter is currently on hold due to potential performance reasons.

So the way you are doing it seems to be the right way given the functionality that is available currently, but this might change as the framework is now in alpha.